# Populate common page elements from a database

Tags: .net, webforms, ef-code-first

I'm still relatively new to .net webforms and for my next project I'd like to do something I haven't done before in populating page elements common to every page from a database.

So for example, I might have a news article, an information page, a contact form etc and whilst the content of each would be different, they would all need data for the title, meta data and an h1 tag. I'd also like to store "tags" for each page, similar to how you might do on a blog, but when the user clicks a tag, it shows every related page, not just (for example) all of the news articles tagged with a certain tag (I can code all this, just asking about how to structure the data).

My idea is to create a class as follows (I work with EF code first)...

```
public class PageCommon
{
        public int PageCommonId { get; set; }
        public string AbsolutePath { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
        public string H1 { get; set; }
        public string Tags { get; set; }
        public virtual NewsArticle NewsArticle { get; set; }
        public virtual InformationPage InformationPage { get; set; }
        public virtual OtherPageType OtherPageType { get; set; }
}
```

So each time a page is loaded, I check the AsbolutePath and get the matching data from the database.

Is using AbsolutePath the correct way to do this, or is there a better option?  I haven't really been able to find any example of such a thing online, so just looking for some advice from people more knowledgable than me as to how they would accomplish this task.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that's not a bad way to do it.  As long as you have the PageCommonId, if you later want to restructure your physical page locations, you can simply adjust the database records.  If you weren't using some type of primary key, you could get into a mess.  As it is, it looks good though, I can't really think of a cleaner way to accomplish this without more complexity.

Comment: thanks, it's reassuring to know I'm thinking things through correctly!